# A strange verb from Mathematica's WordList

Tags: string-manipulation, natural-language

The first word returned by `WordList["Verb"]` is `"aah"`, even though I think it actually an interjection, I still wonder whether there lies any rationale in it; or is it just a bug?

Comment: It is a rarely used form of "be" (2nd pers. singular): "You ahh so wrong!". The verb appears in some famous songs as well like "We ahh the champions" and ["Youth of a nation"](https://youtu.be/0lI_YSFjhgY?t=70). ( I hope I'm still allowed to make jokes as a moderator).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jokes aside, it indeed seems to be a verb in the English language. Look at this [wiki entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aah#Verb):

> Verb: aah (third-person singular simple present aahs, present participle aahing, simple past and past participle aahed)

An example would be

> Everyone who came by oohed and aahed over her new appearance.

Comment: Wow! (only word I can say about it)

Comment: For what it's worth, it's in the OED as well:  "To say ‘ah’ as an expression of surprise, wonder, realization, etc. Frequently in collocation with *ooh* or *oh*."

Comment: Ooh...? Aah...! (The only words I can say about this.)